# Contacts.requestPermission callBack is not working in Android (react-native-contacts)

Tags: react-native, user-permissions

**i am using react-native-contacts.**

i have tested multiple time but it didn't work in android.
on Allow click it should call the callBack Function :
Please see my code :

```
Contacts.checkPermission( (err, permission) => {
  if(permission === 'undefined' || permission === 'denied'){
    Contacts.requestPermission( (err, permission) => {
      console.log(permission);
      console.log('ITS SHOULD CALL THIS BLOCK OF CODE and i have tested many times but this call back function is not being executed.');
    })
  }
  if(permission === 'authorized'){
    console.log(permission);
  }
});
```

Is there any solution or am i doing it wrong!! ?

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation,

> checkPermission (callback) - checks permission to access Contacts ios only
>   requestPermission (callback) - request permission to access Contacts ios only
>   Callbacks

it's ios only.